# How to get scaled bitmap with respect to screen size with out getting Out of memory exception

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

In my activity I am creating a Bitmap of the width and height same as the device resolution (width and height )

what I am doing

> Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight,
>   Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

and screenWidth and screenHeight is

```
    screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Now if I make this bitmap I get my heap goes up to 19mb , which is not so good.

So tell me 2 things

**1. What is a good way of creating the bitmap with respect to screen with and height with minimum memory consumed**

**2. How can I destroy the bitmap after using it ?**

Please provide me a little source code or link of source code.

Comment: you might want to check this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY9aaXHx8yA

Comment: @iGoDa By reading developer site I am exactly understand this , but I want the solution according to my need, I want to get bitmap of screen size mean while it should be at its minimum size

Comment: You can destroy the bitmap by calling destroyDrawingCache() method.For example:iv.destroyDrawingCache() or frame.destroyDrawingCache().Here iv and frame are ImageView and FrameLayout respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What is a good way of creating the bitmap with respect to screen with and height with minimum memory consumed ?

   1. Never ever create a `Bitmap` with the `screen height or width`, because that will be very huge based on the `density` of the device.Instead use the `height` and `width` of the screen and calculate the `aspect ratio`. Now fix the `height` to a constant value (like 1200px) and then calculate the `width` based on the `aspect ratio`. The `ImageView` or any other view will scale this properly.
   2. If you really want transparency then use `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`, if not could use `RGB_565` or something else from the list here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html
   3. Follow below points if you are not creating a fresh `bitmap` but decoding the `bitmap` from some resource:

      1. You need to use `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` to reduce the `sampling`. So how to calculate the `inSampleSize` if you already know the height and width? Refer this here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
      2. So you do all this, and still the `inSampleSize` is not high enough and you get the `OutOfMemoryError` ? Don't worry, if this is the case, you need to `catch` this `OutOfMemoryError` and in that increase your `inSampleSize` and do the bitmap decode again. Put this logic in a loop, so the crash never happens.
2. How can I destroy the bitmap after using it ?

   1. This is really simple. Make sure to call the `Bitmap.recycle()` method. And remove all reference to the bitmap. Once you do this, the resource will be released and GC will do the cleaning up.

**UPDATE:** When you create the a bitmap with `screen_width` and `screen_height` you would end up with a huge bitmap. Instead create a less resolution bitmap that fits the whole screen. You can see the following code on how this is done.

```
    float screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    float screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    float aspectRatio  = screenWidth/screenHeight;

    int modifiedScreenHeight = 1000;
    int modifiedScreenWidth = (int) (modifiedScreenHeight * aspectRatio);

    Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(modifiedScreenWidth, modifiedScreenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Now you got the bitmap with the right aspect ratio. You could use this bitmap as it is in the `ImageView` to fill the whole screen. Make sure you put `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for the `ImageView`.

Comment: can you please eloborate what do you mean by never create a Bitmap with the screen height or width but use the height and width of the screen and calculate the aspect ratio.

Comment: I want to make a bitmap which expend to all over the width and height of screen ? what would you suggest , please explain with code ,, Please

Comment: thats great , but one point is still not clear for me .. you are making this
 int modifiedScreenHeight = 1000;
How come Do we know that this is right height for all devices  ?

Comment: This 1000 is not about the height of the screen, but the resolution of the image. You need to select this value based on the memory you afford. I believe that a 1200px width or height image looks good in all phones.

Comment: by doing this , I got the following error 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

Comment: Yes ideally it should be. I think your `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` are in `int` data type. Hence when you divide them, `aspectRatio` will be 0. So make them as `float` data type. You should make sure that `aspectRatio` is not 0.

Comment: yeah , I just debug that and found the same reason you told , i predict the same

Comment: last question , lower the  modifiedScreenHeight would lower the bitmap size and also size in heap ? or it would increase

Comment: lowering the `modifiedScreenHeight` or `modifiedScreenWidth` will lower the bitmap size, this in turn will lower the heap size.

Comment: and it will cover all screen though its resolution is not good though it not look good?

Comment: My main concern is to fill the screen , and get minimum heap size , no matter how bad does it looks

Comment: 1000 will look good in all phones. If you are going for a tablet then you could go a bit higher. It all depends on the `screenWidth` and `screenHeight`. I usually would calculate the `modifiedSceenWidth` as `min(screenWidth/2, 1000)`. The lower value you choose for `modifiedScreenHeight`, the lower the quality of the image will be, but heap size will be less. If you don't care about the quality, then go ahead with 1000 or less.

Comment: well henry how about after creating this bitmap , then scaling it before loading into memory , how about that ?

Comment: The moment you create the `bitmap`, it's loaded in memory and hence your heap size will increase. You could then scale it and use that and `recyle()` the initial `bitmap`. Once GC gets called, your heap size will decrease again.

Comment: oh thats a really good point , cant we create and scale it at the same time ?

Comment: No, you can't. Creation means memory allocation. So you need to create it with the right size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93655/discussion-between-coas-mckey-and-henry).

Comment: I'm developing a game using Android canvas, and I need to create a bitmap the size of the screen, to draw the background of the game (the background is being drawn dynamically). Since allocating such huge size on a bitmap might cause an OutOfMemoryError, what's the best approach to do that?

Comment: Do you really need a new bitmap? Try to draw directly on your custom view's canvas, rather than creating an additional bitmap.