# Canvas Reducing Image Quality Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am using canvas for modifying my image. However, I am having a problem. If I use options.inSampleSize = 4; the image becomes too small and the quality degrades. However, if I don't give, it overflows from memory and gives an error.

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 1;//Tried 4-But image quality too low


        Bitmap original1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePathF, options);

      int width = original1.getWidth();
        int height = original1.getHeight();
        int bounding = dpToPx(Math.round(height));


        float xScale = ((float) bounding) / width2;
        float yScale = ((float) bounding) / height2;
        float scale = (xScale <= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;


        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale);


        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(original1, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

          Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Text Color
        //Paint alphaChannel = new Paint();
        //alphaChannel.setAlpha(100);
        paint.setAlpha(100);
        paint.setTextSize(20 * scale);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)); // Text Overlapping Pattern
        paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");
        paint.setTypeface(font);

        int x = (width2)/2;
        //int y = Math.round(height1)+(Math.round(height1) - Math.round(height2) / 2);
        int y = Math.round(height);
        int yOffset=calcYoff(gText, 0, 0, paint, canvas, Math.round(20 * scale), width);
```

//            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(original1, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

```
              mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, scaledBitmap);//original1);//
          canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            //canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
            mDrawable.draw(canvas);


            getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File(imagePathF)));



            super.onDraw(canvas);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error--------->", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Here is my current Error Log.

> 11-09 03:21:56.849  12345-12345/com.example.chkee.appfront E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.chkee.appfront, PID: 12345
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32 bits
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:812)
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:789)
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:720)
>               at com.example.chkee.ScrapBook.AddNotes$Draw2d.onDraw(AddNotes.java:288)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15247)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14183)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14205)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14975)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14178)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14205)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14975)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14178)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14205)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14975)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14178)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14205)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14975)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14178)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14205)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14975)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15250)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2906)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14183)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14205)
>               at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
>               at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
>               at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2536)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)

The commented part shows a couple of things more I tried.
Also I tried

```
Bitmap mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(Size, Size,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBackgroundImage);
```

But it makes my whole Image black and drawing on it does not effect the canvas, it remains black.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not create a bitmap with full `height` and `width`. Try to reduce the height or width without affecting the aspect ratio.
2. If inSampleSize = 4 is reducing clarity, go for something less than that.
3. Why are you creating another bitmap `scaledBitmap`? If you really want to create a scaled bitmap, try `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`.
4. Don't forget to call `Bitmap.recycle()` once you don't need a `bitmap`.

For more detailed info on the above points read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33394336/4747587

**UPDATE:** The crash happened not because of `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`, but because of the below line of code:

```
 Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(original1, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

Replace this with:

```
 Bitmap scaledBitmap= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original1, (int)(width/1.5f), (int)(height/1.5f), false);
```

So, play around with the `1.5f` value here to one that suits you. You are trying to create a `bitmap` the same size as the screen with full resolution. That would take huge memory. Instead you need to create a smaller image. All this is well documented in the above link.

Comment: though all the examples state to use options.inScaled, but I did not get the desired result even with using that. :( The image still reduces it size. I just want a bare minimum code that does not reduce the size of the image upon editing. The recycle() helps to avoid Out of Memory exception.

Comment: Updated my answer.. Try to create a scaled bitmap with less width and height. Also call `original1.recycle()` after creating the `scaledBitmap`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to modify your image you can do it at run time.  Using this link you will find more details .

[Quality problems when resizing an image at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231817/quality-problems-when-resizing-an-image-at-runtime)

But, there is another way to stop 'bad image quality after your resizing or scaling your bitmap . You can Disable scaling on bitmap load from resources using:

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), path, options);
```

Also As **[#Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4747587/henry)** Suggested you can use :

```
 Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
```

[How to get scaled bitmap with respect to screen size with out getting Out of memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392964/how-to-get-scaled-bitmap-with-respect-to-screen-size-with-out-getting-out-of-mem/33394336#33394336)

Comment: though all the examples state to use options.inScaled, but I did not get the desired result even with using that. :( The image still reduces it size. I just want a bare minimum code that does not reduce the size of the image upon editing. The recycle() helps to avoid Out of Memory exception.